# Invertible, Positive and Isometry Operator.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, proof-verification

**Let $T ∈ L(V )$ and $T = SP$, where $S$ is an isometry and $P$ is a positive operator. Prove that $T$ is invertible if and only if $P$ is invertible.**

Here is my approach:

$\implies:$ $T = SP$ by taking the adjoint => $T^* = S^* P^* = > T^* = PS^* $ (since P is positive)
By multiplying $T$ to both sides, we have $T^*T = PS^*T = PS^*SP= P^2 $. 
Note that $T^*T$ is invertible since T is invertible. Then $I = P^2=> P^{-1} I = P$ Hence, P is invertible.

$\Longleftarrow:$ $T = SP$ by taking the adjoint => $T^* = S^* P^* = > T^* = PS^* $ (since P is positive)
By multiplying $T$ to both sides, we have $T^*T = PS^*T = PS^*SP$. 
Note that $P^*P$ is invertible since P is invertible. Then $T^*T = I=> T^{-1} I = T$ Hence, T is invertible.

Please give me feedback whether my answer is right or wrong.Your suggestions and hints are greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: i don't understand why the positivity of $P$ is needed. if $S$ is an isometry, then $S$ is invertible. with that, $T$ is invertible iff $P$ is.

Comment: Well it is in the question. Any feedback for my answer?

Comment: if $P$ is invertible, then $T$ is invertible and $T^{-1} = P^{-1}S^{-1}.$ similarly if $T$ is invertible, then $P^{-1} = T^{-1}S.$ am i missing something? what is the deal with the adjoints?

Comment: so just one line prove the whole statement?

Comment: i guess so. i can't find any thing wrong with it. can you?

Comment: i don't think your answer is wrong. what about my answer?

Comment: @abel depending on definitions, isometries are not necessarily invertible (e.g. the right shift operator on a Hilbert space).  They are necessarily injective, though.

Comment: @Omnomnnomnom  yes, you are right. i was thinking finite dimensional $V.$

Comment: @abel Would you look at my comment about the answer under Omnomnoom's answer?

Answer (score 1):

Some comments:

- You make a mistake at the very beginning: you write $T^* = (SP)^* = S^*P^*$ rather than $P^*S^*$.  I suppose this is a typo. If it isn't, explain what you're going for here.
- You should probably elaborate on the implication $T$ is an invertible isometry $\implies T^*T = I$.
- Finally, I have no idea what $T^*T = I \implies T^{-1} I = T$ is supposed to mean.

---

As of now, I don't have enough information to tell you whether your proof is correct. It would help if you responded to my points and wrote out the definitions you're using for "isometry" and "positive operator".

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, Here is the definition of isometry and poistive operator. Isometry: An operator $S \in V $ is isometry if $||Sv|| = ||v||$ for all $v\in V $. In other words, an operator is isometry if it preserves lengths. Every Isometries is invertible. Positive opetrator: An operator $T\in V$ is poisitve operator if T is self-adjoint and $<Tv,v> \ge  0$ for all $v \in V$

Comment: @needhelp "every isometry is invertible" assumes either that isometries are injective or that $V$ is finite dimensional.

Comment: How about $ T^2 = P^2$ => then P is invertible since T is invertible. Does it prove the statement? For your first comment,i get $T^* = S^* P^* = > T^* = PS^* $ since P is positive by using the definition that states every positive operators is self-adjoint. My conlusion was wrong as you pointed out in 3rd comment. Thanks!